# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in omega_layout_load_theme_assets() (line 454 of omega.inc)

Tags: panels, theming

I am using Omega 4. Have created a subTheme with two layouts, home and subsite. In Panels (3), I am creating new default site template variants (which all use the subsite layout), each variant has its own name and variant-specific content.

I get the following error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in omega_layout_load_theme_assets() (line 454 of ../sites/all/themes/omega/omega/includes/omega.inc).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

amy.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Omega 4. You should create an issue at Omega's issue queue.

Comment: After much troubleshooting and eventually finding the right person at work to help me, the solution was found! In my .info file for my sub theme, my layout sytlesheet references were missing an empty bracket. So, omega.inc was expecting an array of arrays, but was only receiving an array.                                                       ORIGINAL .info file: layout[subpage][stylesheets][all] = css/layouts/subpage/subpage.layout.css                                       CORRECTED .info file: layout[subpage][stylesheets][all][] = css/layouts/subpage/subpage.layout.css